# Monetization and billing in WSO API Manager concepts

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, billing

I do this question because I see it has been already done, but the answers are not clear.

I have enabled monetization in WSO2 API Manager 2.5.0 (integrated with WSO2 Analytics and WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager) following [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Monetization+of+APIs).

With an API subscriber user (registered on API Store), I subscribe to a commercial API (it has throttling tiers with *subscription_fee* and *charge_per_extra* properties), selecting a subscription throttling tier.
I am redirected to the Billing Engine, so I sign up and enter the bank account information. After that, I am redirected to the API Store.

It is OK. But with the new user created in the Billing Engine, the **API subscriber user can log in the Billing Engine and define new plans and generate invoices**. It doesn't make sense for me.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909535/article-enabling-monetization-of-apis-with-wso2-api-manager-related-question), API developer user is separated from the API developer user. But I dont understand that.
In my ideal use case:

- API creator user (or API publisher user) should bill (generate and
  emit the invoice) to the API subscriber user depending of number of
  API requests.
- API subscriber user (which is developer of his/her app) will
  receive the invoice, and will do the payment.

So, **what is the difference between API subscriber user and API developer user?**

And also, I would like to have same throttling tiers than billing plans in my platform. And not allow to subscribers create new plans (neither generate their own invoices). **How can I do it?**

There is other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121231/in-wso2-api-monetization-why-subscriber-will-fill-details-regarding-plan) explaining the flow and asking clarification about this, but the answer says it looks like a mistake in the docs. It is not true, because Billing Engine actually has the described flow.

Other [question](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/1045) without success.

Answer (score 2):

@Pedro, ideally subscriber cannot define billing plan in the system. Since the billing engine is a demo app for monetization, it doesn't include the role validation.

Comment: Yes, I agree, API subscriber user should NOT define new billing plan, but he actually does! He can define new billing plans once he has registered as a user in the billing system. Why?

Comment: @Pedro, yes subscriber cannot define plan in the billing engine. And it is a bug in the current version. Can you please raise and report a git issue?